# How to get return value of a function in wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress, return-value, page-title

I have a function in my wordpress theme and i am trying to get the return value of this function to check if it's "Untitled".

Please tell me the correct syntax.

my code looks like this -

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

and it prints Untitled. I want to check when it gives me the "Untitled" value.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [the_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) method but pass in the optional parameters. The 3rd arg controls if the method echo's or return's.

```
$title = the_title('','',false); // Display the title (TRUE) or return it for use in PHP (FALSE).
if($title=='Untitled'){
 ...
}
```

Comment: i did the same. but `$title = get_the_title($ID);` this line also prints the title.

Comment: sorry - see updated answer. you need to pass in the third method argument.

Comment: The_title() is not working as it was working in your earlier answer. It always printing `Untitled` now. However i have made it work by giving it in <div> and making this <div> hidden. ;)